# Ansible & Mitogen ERROR! Invalid play strategy specified: mitogen_linear

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to setup mitogen to run with ansible but keep getting invalid play strategy errors. Below is my ansible.cfg, ansible --version, and pip3 show mitogen output.

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = false
strategy_plugins = /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
strategy = mitogen_linear
[persistent_connection]
connect_timeout = 60
```

```
user@server:~/ansible$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = /home/user/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
```

```
user@server:~/ansible$ pip3 show mitogen
Name: mitogen
Version: 0.3.3
Summary: Library for writing distributed self-replicating programs.
Home-page: https://github.com/mitogen-hq/mitogen/
Author: David Wilson
Author-email: None
License: New BSD
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Comment: https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/changelog.html#v0-3-0-unreleased => since you use ansible 2.10+, you need version 3.0 of mitogen which is unreleased. Knowing that ansible 2.10 was EOL in 2022 and that the current version is 2.15, I actually suspect the project you are trying to use is dead.

Comment: ^ indeed. Do not use mitogen, as it also might introduce other small glitches. Especially for production workloads, just stick w “plain” Ansible.